# Calculation not returning correct value

Tags: c++, visual-c++, math, io

I was asked to write this program: *"A software company sells a package that retails for $99. Quantity discounts are given according to the following table:*

```
QUANTITY    DISCOUNT  
10-19       20%  
20-49       30%  
50-99       40%  
100 or more 50%
```

*Write a program that asks for the number of units sold and computes the total cost of the purchase.
Input Validation: Make sure the number of units is greater than 0"*

This is what I have so far:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>           //String class- a string of text
#include <iomanip>          //Required for setw= the field width of the value after it
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    double sales, charges, numOfUnits = 0,
           rateA = .20, rateB = .30, rateC = .40, rateD = .50;

    //Set the numeric output formatting:
    cout << fixed << showpoint << setprecision(2);
    cout << "Enter the quantity for your order: ";
    cin >> sales;
            
    // Determine the discount:
    double PRICE=99.0;
    if (sales >= numOfUnits)
    if (sales >= 10 && sales <= 19 )
    rateA;
    charges = PRICE - rateA *sales;
    if (sales >= 20 && sales <= 49)
    rateB;
    charges = PRICE - rateB *sales;
    if (sales >= 50 && sales <= 99)
    rateC;
    charges = PRICE - rateC *sales;
    if (sales > 100 )
    rateD;
    charges = PRICE - rateD *sales;

    cout << "Your total price for this quantity is: $" <<charges 
         << " per unit."<< endl;
    cout << "That is an invalid number. Run the program again\n "
         << "and enter a number greater than\n" 
         << numOfUnits << ".\n";
}
```

After compiling, the output does not give me the right answers. Maybe my math is wrong, or my flow is off? any suggestions?

I do not want anyone to write this for me, but maybe give me some pointers

Comment: Explain what is going wrong, and change the title.

Comment: This isn't Facebook, so please change the title of the question to actually reflect the contents of your post :-/

Comment: `if (sales >= 10 && sales <= 19 ) rateA;` What is that `rateA` supposed to be doing there?

Comment: `sales` is a `double`, so `cin >> sales` could result in `sales` having the value 19.5.  Such a value would miss the many `if()` clauses.  Recommend `if (sales >= 10 && sales < 20 )`, etc. instead.

Answer (score 4):

You need to use braces `{}` around multi-line conditions

```
if (sales >= 10 && sales <= 19 )
    rateA;
    charges = PRICE - rateA *sales;
```

is actually

```
if (sales >= 10 && sales <= 19 )
    rateA;
charges = PRICE - rateA *sales;
```

i.e. `rateA` is executed conditionally and the update to `charges` is always executed.

Also, statements like `rateA;` have no effect so should either be updated or removed.

Comment: Thanks, I removed the rateA, rateB and so forth. I think it was just confusing me.

Answer (score 0):

This sort of construct:

```
if (sales >= 50 && sales <= 99)
rateC;
charges = PRICE - rateC *sales;
```

does:

```
if (sales >= 50 && sales <= 99)
    rateC;

charges = PRICE - rateC *sales;
```

In other words, `charges` is always calculated with `rateC`, rather than only being so when the sales is in the relevant range. `rateC` inside the if-statement is also completely useless - it doesn't "do" anything with `rateC`, the it's just telling the compiler to "go look at this value, then throw it away" [which the compiler probably translates to "do nothing at all", because "looking" at `rateC` doesn't actually have any visible effect outside of that statement, so it can be removed].

Comment: {  if (order >= 10 && order <= 19)
  discount = .20 *99;

 }

Answer (score 0):

On a quick glance, I think the math is off a bit.

It should be :

```
double originalPrice = PRICE * sales;
if (sales >= 10 && sales <= 19 )
  charges = originalPrice - (rateA * originalPrice);
else if (sales >= 20 && sales <= 49)
```

and so on..

Comment: Yes I got it thanks, just changed the words around and got rid of the rates.